# What is the most elegant way to create nested json using swift 4?

Tags: json, swift, encodable

What is the most elegant way to create JSON from this structure with the only one parameter

```
    struct SessionStorage: Encodable {
        var value: String

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        /// the magic
        }

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case params
        }
    }
```

into this JSON-string?

`{"params": {"value": "{value}"}}`

I don't want to create nested structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Encode the dictionary as `[String: SessionStorage]`

   ```
   struct SessionStorage: Encodable {
       var value: String
   }

   let session = SessionStorage(value: "Foo")

   do {
       let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(["params" : session])
       print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)
   } catch { print(error) }
   ```
2. Use an envelope struct

   ```
   struct Envelope : Encodable {
       let params : SessionStorage
   }


   struct SessionStorage: Encodable {
       var value: String
   }

   let envelope = Envelope(params : SessionStorage(value: "Foo"))

   do {
       let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(envelope)
       print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)
   } catch { print(error) }
   ```

IMHO it's not a question of elegance, it's a question of efficiency. The elegance lies in not to specify `encode(to` and `CodingKeys`

Comment: nice avatar  hat:)

Comment: @Vyacheslav That's one of the earned Winter Bash hats.